# Redis pipeline vs mget

Tags: redis

I'm looking into using either [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget) or [pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining), but I can't seem to find the information on `MGET` that I'm looking for

My use case is to replace 50 `GET` calls with either `MGET` or `pipeline`

What I found so far is:

When we use `pipeline`, commands are not guaranteed to be executed one after the another and other client commands could be executed in between. This means that when we group `GET` commands with `pipeline`, redis won't be blocked for O(50) and other clients will get a chance to execute their commands (50 being number of `GET` calls that I'm grouping)

On the other hand, for the command `MGET` I was not able to find the information on how it works - when we call MGET with 50 keys, will the command block the redis instance until it gets all the keys? How does the `MGET` work?

Comment: Can you explain why you would need Redis to block and not serve other clients when it's serving one MGET or pipeline of commands? In general, any server should be capable of serving multiple requests in parallel as long as it can maintain data consistency. Given that you're going to be calling GET (either with MGET or pipeline), do you expect other clients to not change the value while you'll be trying to GET the value?

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough, but I don't want redis to block anything. I know redis is single threaded and that it will execute one command at a time. I was just wondering what would be the impact of replacing 50 `GET` calls with either `MGET` or `pipeline`. I couldn't find any info on how `MGET` works, except that it has O(N), where N is number of keys. And I was wondering if it will fetch all 50 keys in one blocking call or other clients would get a chance to execute commands in between those 50 calls

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Redis is single-threaded, any single command will block until it's finished. Including `MGET`.

Pipelines are just a way of batching commands, they don't block other clients.

So: `MGET` will block and a pipeline won't.